# How do I write sum of squares and degrees of freedom for multiple Latin squares put together?

Tags: self-study, anova, linear-model, experiment-design, latin-square

I have notes from my professor in which a Latin square model ($s$ treatments in an $s \times s$ square) is described as follows:

\begin{align*}
Y_{ijk} &= \mu + \alpha_i + \beta_j + \gamma_k + \epsilon_{ijk}\\
\text{SS}_{\text{treatment}} &= s \sum_{i = 1}^s (\bar Y_{i\cdot \cdot} - \bar Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot})^2\\
\text{SS}_{\text{row}} &= s \sum_{j = 1}^s (\bar Y_{\cdot j \cdot} - \bar Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot})^2\\
\text{SS}_{\text{column}} &= s \sum_{k = 1}^s (\bar Y_{\cdot \cdot k} - \bar Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot})^2\\
\text{SS}_{\text{total}} &= \sum_j \sum_k (Y_{ijk} - \bar Y_{\cdot \cdot \cdot})^2\\
\text{SS}_{\text{residual}} &= \text{ by subtraction}\\ \\
\text{df } \text{SS}_{\text{treatment}} &= \text{df } \text{SS}_{\text{row}} = \text{df } \text{SS}_{\text{column}} = s - 1\\
\text{df } \text{SS}_{\text{treatment}} &= s^2 - 1\\
\text{df } \text{SS}_{\text{residual}} &= (s - 1)(s - 2).
\end{align*}

I was asked to produce a design for testing five gasoline additives in five cars over ten days, doing five runs per day. I took two Latin squares, put them side by side and got the following:

[image]

I think my design is on the right track. However I'm completely lost as to how to generalize the above formulae to my current design. I have been searching some textbooks and found some ANOVA tables (see appendix) but I can't make sense of them for my situation.

I appreciate any help.

**Appendix:**

[image]

[image]